# OpenAI API works in local but returns a 404 error on hosting (hPanel)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, openai-api

This Laravel project using the *openai-php/laravel* works great in local but I can't manage to get a response on the online prod hosted version. Though I uploaded all the project files and everything is exactly the same, the URL, the route and the following code, when I send a POST request it just returns a 404 error.

> POST DOMAIN_NAME/api/send 404
> fetchAndUpdateHTML @ (index):67
> (index):90 Fetch error: Server error.

I don't know if it's a route issue, an URL that would need to be redefined for an online use of the API...
This project is a **subdomain** but I've tried all sorts of paths for the URL for the JS...

**The JavaScript :**

```
//CSRF TOKEN
const csrfToken = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.openai.com/v1/completions', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', csrfToken);

//VARIABLES
const button = document.getElementById('button-submit');
const chatWindow = document.getElementById('chat-window');
const url = '{{ url('/api/send') }}';
const inputField = document.getElementById('input');
const clean = document.getElementById('button-clean');

//API FETCH AND HTML UPDATE
function fetchAndUpdateHTML() {
    const input = document.getElementById('input').value;
    if(isInputValid(input)){
        chatWindow.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div class="messages-user">
                        <div class="__user">
                            <p>${input}</p>
                        </div>
                        <img src="{{ asset('/images/avatar.png') }}" alt="Avatar">
                        <div style="clear: both"></div>
                        </div>`);
        inputField.value = '';

        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({input: input}),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.text();
            } else {
                throw new Error('Server error.');
            }
        }).then(function (data) {
            chatWindow.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div class="messages-bot">
                        <img src="{{ asset('/images/chatbot.png') }}" alt="Avatar">
                        <div class="__bot">
                            <p>${data}</p>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        `);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Fetch error:', error.message);
        });
    }
}
```

**The api.php :**

```
    use App\Http\Controllers\ChatBotController;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

    Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });

    Route::post('send', [ChatBotController::class, 'sendChat']);
```

**The Controller :**

```
public function sendChat(Request $request){
    $result = OpenAI::completions()->create([
        ‘max-token’ => 150,
        ‘model’ => ‘text-davinci-003’,
        ‘prompt’ => $request->input
    ]);

    $response = array_reduce(
        $result->toArray()['choices'],
        fn(string $result, array $choice) => $result . $choice['text'], ""
    );
    
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: If you are getting a 404 when trying to POST to _your_ system, then the API you are trying to call afterwards, has very little to do with this.

Comment: @CBroe Do you mean my POST request is incorrect from the start? I can't really see another issue than the route/url, as the POST is working locally...

Comment: I still can't find how to fix this, I've tried many different URLs...